# Error when pasting image with CTRL + V FROALA

Tags: froala

I started the basic version of Froala with version 4, the problem is that if I paste an image with CTRL + v, it does not appear in the editor because it presents a message that is "**Image file type is invalid**", but if I use the image icon it uploads without problems and remains visible in the editor. How can I fix it?

[Preview error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lIPf.png)

This is my code

```
<script>
  new FroalaEditor('#description',{
   toolbarButtons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'fontFamily', 'color','paragraphFormat', 'align', 'formatOL', 'formatUL', 'outdent', 'indent','insertImage','insertTable','|', 'undo', 'redo'],
   imageInsertButtons: ['imageBack', '|', 'imageUpload'],
   quickInsertTags: [],
   language: 'es',
   attribution: false,
   charCounterCount: false,
   imageUploadURL: '/upload_files',
   imageUploadParams: {
         _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        id: '{{$model->id}}'
      }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem when using the following source

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/froala-editor@4.0.4/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js

if i changed to this - it solved the problem

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/4.0.4/js/froala_editor.min.js

Comment: I'm still not having problems, maybe it's also because I downloaded the zip file and I'm not working on cdn.

Comment: using angular version of froala, "angular-froala-wysiwyg" and still facing this issue. Cant find alternate but to disable pasting image.

Answer (score 0):

The problem we detected was its a different file type when copy/pasted. If you paste a png file - it will be `image/png;base64`. Allowing `png;base64` in allowed image file types `imageAllowedTypes` sends the request to server but then its upto the server to handle that as well.